# controls layout WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

i have a LOB application with 30 fields to put in a form.
I found it very painful to put them in the window with a grid.

is there a productive way to build entry forms in WPF .
Thanks
John

Comment: If you're going to downvote the newbie, at least explain why. If the question didn't please you and you can't be bothered to educate, just move on.

Comment: @msw: While I agree with your point in general, in this particular case it seems that the asker himself can't be bothered to use Google first, or in case he has used it and wasn't satisfied, at least describe specifically what the problems are and how existing solutions are unsatisfactory. Instead, the asker expects the community to solve his problems for him, without doing anything himself. While such approach could be OK in other circumstances, it is certainly unacceptable for somebody who considers himself an engineer. (just for the record: it wasn't me who downvoted the question)

Comment: @fyodor: thanks. As I know zero about WPF I didn't know that this was a "Google It For Me" question. I agree with you in full in the general case, and based on the OP's response, in the particular as well.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `StackPanel`

Comment: Ummm... No, I suppose I couldn't. But take a look at this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61853/anyone-using-wpf-for-real-lob-applications